# wireless mouse not getting detected in my laptop

Tags: bluetooth

my new wireless mouse is not getting detected in my laptop, whereas it is working fine in all other systems and laptops. when i plug in the USB it is saying device not installed successfully i.e.(drivers not found). i checked in Google for wireless mouse drivers for my laptop(lenovo g580) but i can't find it. previously i disable Bluetooth application because of bTTray main window.exe error. is there any relation between wireless mouse connection and Bluetooth ?? please help mee... if there drivers available.. please let me know

Comment: You might want to go to Lenovo's site and check the support forums there. Stackoverflow.com is for programming questions, so you won't get the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are u using? If it is windows 7 or 8, then go to device manager and update USB drivers after right clicking the USB entries.

Comment: i'm using windows 7 ultimate. it is copywrited version... so i can't update my driver's...

Comment: Do u mean genuine version?

Comment: No it's not genuine version. it is pirated version

Comment: There is no difference with that. U can update drivers using devise manager. the only thing u can't do is windows update, but u can do drivers update.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Remove USB receiver and wireless mouse battery for 5 seconds. ...
Go to RUN (Win Logo + R) and type “devmgmt.msc” to open device manager.
Now find Mice and other pointing devices and find your wireless mouse.
Now right click on your wireless mouse and click Scan for hardware changes.

source:https://www.wiknix.com/solved-wireless-mouse-not-working/